# Fr/En differences in the use of et/and and ou/or

Tags: conjonctions

I often see the word *ou* where I would expect *and* in English - for example, I have just read *le phénomène #Mbappé, aussi bien physique que mental, décrypté par Wenger, Platini ou Deschamps*.

In this sentence, would *... Wenger, Platini et Deschamps* suggest that there was one analysis / décryptage done by the three of them as a joint effort? In other words, is *ou* preferred because it makes it clear that they are each giving their own analysis?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not necessarily a single analysis but using ***et*** would restrict the number of persons doing the analysis to these three individuals.

On the other hand, saying *Wenger, Platini **ou** Deschamps* indeed means the analysis are distinct to each other, but doesn't prevent other, non named people, to provide their own analysis, especially as the [tweet](https://twitter.com/Batdesprez/status/1211956205800902656) talks about a series that will last a week.

Comment: Thank you. So if the editor were to say *ce serait peut-être intéressant de faire décrypter le phénomène Mbappé par Wenger, Platini ou Deschamps*, would you be thinking of a single article by one of those three, or a series? If I want to refer to one article, my instinct is to say *ce serait peut-être intéressant de faire décrypter le phénomène Mbappé par un Wenger, un Platini ou bien un Deschamps*, but my instincts are not always right...

Comment: 1. A single article by one of these. 2. Using *ou bien* keeps that meaning but using the indefinite *un* before the names suggests a single article by someone like them, likely but not necessarily one of them.